# Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS

Tags: node.js, angular, sqlite, nativescript

I'm trying to use NativeScript + Angular + SQLite to create a mobile application and following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUXDrf5q6W4) video. At 3:00, it says to run the command `tns platform add ios` in the folder and I get the error "Applications for platform iso can not be built on this OS." The OS that I'm running is Windows 10 Home. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure how to fix it and all of the things I've found on it are for mac

Comment: You can't fix it, as such; you need to not be using Windows 10.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahhh. yikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not build apps for iOS using Windows OS, it's not limitation from NativeScript but from Apple itself. You need Xcode to build apps for iOS which can only be installed on Mac OS.

If you have an iOS device with you, you may use [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/) or [Preview](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-preview) to run your code directly on your device from a Windows machine. The CLI / [Sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick) even support cloud builds.

If you like to use Simulators, the only option is to install Mac OS using Virtual Box but that may be terribly slow.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. I though that having that simulator was integral to me being able to follow the tutorial. thanks!